# Uniform convergence of sequence of function.

Tags: real-analysis

Let
\begin{eqnarray}
f_n(x)&=& nx^2, 0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{n}\\
&=& x, \frac{1}{n}< x \leq 1 
\end{eqnarray}
I am trying to show that $f_n$ uniformly converges to a function $f(x)=x$.
Graphically, I could see that the point wise limit is $x$.
Define $M_n=\displaystyle{\sup |f_n(x)-f(x)|}$ . For uniform convergence, lim $M_n=0$.
I can see that
\begin{eqnarray}
f_n(x)-f(x)&=&nx^2-x, \leq x \leq \frac{1}{n}\\
&=&0,\frac{1}{n}< x \leq 1.
\end{eqnarray}
But I have no idea how to proceed with the uniform convergence. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've already found the correct expression for $f_n(x)-f(x)$. All that remains is to compute $\sup_x |f_n(x)-f(x)|$ and show that it converges to zero.

Comment: @Oliver Diaz. I have read this in my undergraduate course. I only know about point wise and uniform convergence of sequences of functions.

Comment: @AdritaChoudhury: you almost have your problem solve by your own. Notice that $M_n=\frac{1}{4n}$ by simple calculus methods and so $M_n \xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$. As for my first comment, now removed, I had misread your question the first time around.